# Adding Shared Folder Trees to Sharepoint Without the Content

Tags: 2010

I'm running SharePoint 2010,
and I want to add folder trees from outside of SharePoint root server so that I could be able to see their content with a link on my SharePoint site.
I don't want to add their content to SharePoint and I want to be able to add meta data to the contents.

I could do this with "Data Sheet View" but it takes a long time. I have a lot of multi-level folders

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use BCS to connect to the file system and show the data as it is stored in SharePoint.

> Business Connectivity Services, which enables users to read and write
>   data from external systems—through web services, databases, and
>   Microsoft .NET Framework assemblies

Here are some usefull links to help you on the way

[Creating Custom Business Connectivity Services Connectors Using SharePoint Server 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff953161.aspx)
[Code Sample: MyFileConnector Custom Indexing Connector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff625800.aspx)

Comment: will I be able to do this without any deep knowledge about coding and only following the steps in the first Article?

Comment: If you follow the steps and download the code it can be done.

Comment: Im getting this error "Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator."

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can only add metadata to content that resides inside a SharePoint site. If you have files in a network share, you can use tools to show the tree view of the network share, but these files are not inside the SharePoint framework and you cannot apply SharePoint metadata to these files.

With tools for remote BLOB storage, the actual content may live outside of SharePoint, but for all intents and purposes, SharePoint still controls the metadata properties for that content.

The Datasheet View is used to display the columns of a SharePoint list in a grid view for easy bulk editing, among other things. I fail to see how the Datasheet View has a connection to files that reside outside of the SharePoint site.

Comment: i don't want to store my files in SharePoint database. i want to have control over them outside of SharePoint. im using Lists, not Library. and I'm already adding metadata to those lists that has a link to outside files. but i want to do that automatically because there are lots of folders. i want to add all my directory structures once. thank you

Comment: That's understandable. But you can only apply SharePoint metadata if the files are stored in a SharePoint context. So, if the files are not stored in SharePoint, then you cannot apply SharePoint metadata.

Comment: I'm already doing it in Lists

Comment: You are doing exactly WHAT in lists? Can you detail that?

Comment: So you found a solution to apply SharePoint metadata to files that are not stored in SharePoint? That's very interesting indeed. Please share. How does it work?